# Collapsing windows to the left?

Tags: shortcut

I have only started using Blender fairly recently, and I was trying to model something when I accidentally pressed a shortcut. I don't know what it was, but it opened an (editable) rendered view of my model. I was trying to revert my screen back to normal, but I don't know what I'm doing. Can anyone help me figure out how to collapse the labeled window (see attached photo)? I've trying dragging the corner to both the right and up, but it won't move.

Thanks! [image: messedupscreen]

Comment: Move the mouse above the line, when the cursor switch to the double arrow, click with the right button and select join area.

Comment: you probably changed the viewing mode to rendered. The shaded sphere on the bottom of the left window just above the timeline to the right of the Edit mode drop down list.